# Monitoring if a file stopped being copied with watchdog

Tags: python, watchdog, python-watchdog

I'm uploading large files (multiple GB) over WebDAV to a server and I would like to see if files are still being copied (preferably check if the file size is still increasing) or if something went wrong and the upload was interrupted.

At the moment I'm using the following code based on the quick start example in the [watchdog package](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/quickstart.html):

```
import sys
import time
import logging
from watchdog.observers import Observer
from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler

class MyHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_created(self, event):
        print("Started")
    def on_modified(self, event):
        print("Finished")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path = '.'
    event_handler = MyHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

But this only gives me output when the file was created on the server and when it's finished uploading. Also, when I interrupt the upload midway it does not tell me that the file finished uploading, it only says that it was created.
How do I now check if a file is actively being uploaded and raise an error when it was interrupted? Can it be done with watchdog or should I use polling instead?

Comment: if this is a linux platform there is always `https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki` pyinotify - allows you to monitor file changes and its event driven so no polling.

Comment: @SamerTufail inotify does not work with my platform and webdav unfortunately.